# Puppet: Merge a Hash with same keys

Tags: hash, merge, key, puppet

I have an array

```
$servers = [192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2]
```

Which should be converted into a Array with hashes of the following form (an array with hashes and as the key "hostname" and the actual value of the array servers):

```
[
    { hostname => 192.168.1.1 }
    { hostname => 192.168.1.2 }
]
```

---

I tried the following:

```
$servers_hash = $servers.reduce({}) |$servermerge, $serverip| {
  $servermerge + { 'hostname' => $serverip }
}
```

The problem with this is, that if two hashes who have the same key are merged with the `+` , the first one gets overwritten. So only `{ hostname => 192.168.1.2 }` is left.

Update: and the following:

```
$servers_array = $servers.reduce([]) |$servermerge, $serverip| {
  $servermerge + { 'hostname' => $serverip }
}
```

Which gives: `[[hostname, 192.168.1.1], [hostname, 192.168.1.2]]`

Comment: I do not believe most languages allow Hashes/Maps/Dictionaries with identical keys, and Puppet is one of them. You likely need a different structure for this.

Comment: Makes sense, but arrays with almost identical hashes should be no problem in my eyes?

Comment: Your logic would work with `+` if you put the hash in an array - `[ { 'hostname => $serverip}]` - but I posted the real answer to what you should do here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149583/327930 (use the `map()` function instead of `reduce()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want as many results as there are entries in the input the easiest (and best) is to use the `map()` function:

```
$servers_array = $servers.map |$ip| { { 'hostname' => $ip } }
```

While the general form for iteration that produces a new value is `reduce()` it is slightly more complicated as you have to construct the resulting array. When doing so in puppet, each append with `<<` operator creates a new copy of the array. If the input array is long this can become a significant overhead. For that reason, the more specialized `map()`, `filter()` etc. iterative functions should be preferred over `reduce()` when it is possible to do so since those function hold a temporary mutable state when they build up the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

If a `+` is used, the righthand side of the code is casted to an array, needles what it was before. With the `<<` this casting isn't done.

```
$servers_array = $servers.reduce([]) |$servermerge, $serverip| {
  $servermerge << { 'hostname' => $serverip }
}
```

Which gives: `[{hostname, 192.168.1.1}, {hostname, 192.168.1.2}]`